# How do I catagorise images in HTML and display all images that have the given catagory clicked via hyperlink

Tags: html, css, image, attributes, tags

[My dummy wallpaper website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awQv6.png) currently has 4 divs each with a list of hyperlinks representing catagories/tags for a dummy wallpaper site I am making.

I want to have png/jpg images (wallpapers) and attribute catagories to them. For example images with game characters will have their own attributed catagory, images with nature will have their own attributed catagory etc. Images need to be able to have multiple catagories since an image might have nature **and** gaming characters such as a mountain in Skyrim wallpaper.

When the hyperlink for nature is clicked then all images with the nature catagory are displayed regardless of all other catagories they have attributed such as artist or resolution/size.

I am trying to find out of what combinations of tools/code to use to assign these catagories to images and how to make the hyperlink display all the images with that catagory regardless of other catagories the given image may have assigned to it.

Here is the code I put for the top left catagories of hyperlinks

```
<h3>Catagories</h3>
                <ol type="1">
                    <li><a href="Gaming.html">Gaming</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Nature.html">Nature</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Graphical.html">Graphical</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Fanmade.html">Fanmade</a></li>
                </ol>
```

Comment: an old pen of mine using classname and css https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/JFdEk might be a hint for you . (click the categorie you want to show picture) . *Aucune* means none, *Tous* means all

Comment: @G-Cyr i really liked what you did..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be extremely hard, if at all possible with HTML alone. You gonna need to use MySQL and PHP to store and show the images.
When making the Table for Database, you need 2 tables, one for attributes and one for images.
[Image table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vJY2.jpg) [Attributes table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p76RS.jpg)

Then when selecting for a category, you can just say:

```
SELECT * FROM attribute WHERE gaming = 1 AND nature = 1
```